# How to make usercentrics cookiebot work with Next.js v14 (app router)

Tags: next.js14

When attempting to include [Usercentrics Cookiebot](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/help/?_gl=1*jwf5e8*_ga*MTg3MDM5NDUwNC4xNzAwNjkyNjA4*_ga_WX15RJ0HZZ*MTcwMDc2NDE4MS4yLjEuMTcwMDc2NTcyNi42MC4wLjA.*_ga_HXY5PN80YH*MTcwMDc2NDM3OS4yLjEuMTcwMDc2NDM4Ny4wLjAuMA..) in my React Next.js app, I encountered an error: "Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418". The banner briefly displays before disappearing.

Here's my initial implementation:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" />
        {isProduction() && (
          <script
            id="Cookiebot"
            src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js"
            data-cbid="<id here>"
            data-blockingmode="auto"
            type="text/javascript"
          ></script>
        )}
      </head>
      <body className={`${urbanist.className} flex flex-col`}>
        <Providers>
          {children}
          <Analytics />
        </Providers>
        {isProduction() && (
          <>
            <script
              id="CookieDeclaration"
              src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/<id here>/cd.js"
              type="text/javascript"
              async
            ></script>
          </>
        )}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Additionally, I tried Next.js's recommended approach using next/script:

```
<Script
  src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js"
  id="Cookiebot"
  data-cbid="<id here>"
  data-blockingmode="auto"
  type="text/javascript"
  strategy="beforeInteractive"
/>

<Script
  src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/<id here>/cd.js"
  id="CookieDeclaration"
  type="text/javascript"
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  async
/>
```

However, this approach led to Cookiebot complaining that the "Cookiebot" ID wasn't set, and https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js couldn't be found.

I'm seeking suggestions to resolve this issue. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, im experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Also same issue for me... When changing page the router is completely broken by cookiebot